# Failed to resolve "System.Void Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverterAttribute::.ctor(System.Type)" reference from "Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, json.net

Keep getting this error after converting my Xamarin.Forms application from a PCL to .NET Standard 1.4 via [this article](https://blog.xamarin.com/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/). I have absolutely no idea what could be causing it as building the projects separately works fine (Forms, iOS and Android projects) but when I attempt to run the app on my device this error gets thrown from the iOS project. The assembly is obviously being referenced fine.

I read online that I may need to reference the PCL version of JSON.NET instead. Is there any possible way to do this via Nuget? Not exactly sure where to go from here.

Comment: I am facing same problem. did you get any solution?

Comment: @RashminJaviya I ended up just creating a new .NET Standard project using the Visual Studio templates and moving my source files over.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, the Newtonsoft.Json is not a direct reference but rather files get copied to my bin on post build event of some other project. I realize post build event script had a problem and dlls couldn't copied. resolving that did work for me.